# Linux finding duplicates send appended files to new directory

Tags: linux, shell

I've been struggling with this,part of a job interview I found online but cant figure it out.

**Obtain a list of paths to all PDF and pdf files within the source
directory.

For every file in this list
Check to see if there is a corresponding doc file in the same
directory.

If there is do nothing

If there is not

Check to see if there is already a PDF file in the target
directory with this name.

If there is not, copy the PDF file to the target
directory as is.

If there is and it is not identical, copy the PDF file to
the target directory but append “_” to the filename.**

**Got the pdf with find but cant loop the files.**

```
find ../mnt -iname "*.pdf"
```

Answer (score 0):

there are lots of ways to do this but starting with your find command

```
for i in $(find ../mnt -iname "*.pdf"); do z=$(basename -s .pdf $i); echo $z;done
```

this will print out a list of filenames with the suffixes removed.  Then it is simple to do something like

```
if [ -e "..mnt/$z.doc" ]; then
```

To check if the doc file is there

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help but all that comes up is this.

Comment: BusyBox v1.21.0 (2013-02-18 15:57:06 WST) multi-call binary.

Usage: basename FILE [SUFFIX]

Strip directory path and .SUFFIX from FILE

Comment: google what basename does, realize that the busybox basename works slightly differently in it's  call semantics to the one I am using and then take a guess at what might work

Comment: for i in $(find /root/first-test -iname "*.pdf"); 
do basename $i
done